# Docker flask app not working - port issues

Tags: python, docker, flask

I am trying to run a flask through docker.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 3000

# run the command
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

My app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

from submission import SubmissionResult

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route("/health")
def health_check():
    return "healthy"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I ran `docker run <my_image>`.

When I hit "/health" on postman, I get an error saying:

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to .
Why this might have happened:
The server couldn't send a response:
Ensure that the backend is working properly
Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
Proxy configured incorrectly
Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
Request timeout:
Change request timeout in Settings > General
```

It's weird because my flask app doesn't show any debugging logs, so presumably the request isn't hitting the server. Am I not exposing the port correctly?

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You are not specifying the output port on the Python code. It maps to the default port, which is 5000. Use `app.run(debug=True, port=3000)` if you want to expose to port 3000. You also have to export the Docker port on host, do this calling `-p 3000:3000` before `<my_image>`. It will tell Docker to map port 3000 of the image to port 3000 of host.

Comment: hm interesting, this worked.  I don't quite understand the purpose of `EXPOSE`  in the Dockerfile though

Comment: EXPOSE is just for documentation. It is a good practice to have it in Dockerfile, because it tells the people that are using Dockerfile the ports that are being used.